# ChartJS bubble plot categorical y-labels with numbers in string plot issue

Tags: chart.js, bubble-chart

I'm using ChartJS (v2.9) to bubble-plot categorical y-axis labels against time series data.

I'm seeing odd behaviour in that if the y-axis category has a numerical value anywhere in the string, the data is not plotted although the label remains.

If I edit it so that there is not numerical values then the data is plotted OK.

Logging the data to the console all looks fine with no errors.

I have seen this with a number of datasets. Has anybody else seen this behaviour with ChartJS bubble plots and could you solve it?

Thanks in advance...

Tony

[plot without number in label string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9H8Kg.png)
[plot with number in label string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qOTs.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to update to Chart.js 3.3 and use these methods:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.3.0/axes/cartesian/category.html

```js
var bubbleBackgroundColor = function() {
            return 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)'
  };
  var bubbleBorderColor = function() {
            return 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)'
  };

  var bubbleChartData = {
    animation: {
      duration: 10
    },
    // Documentation says the tick values tick.min & tick.max must be in the Labels array. So thats what I have below
    
    datasets: [{
      label: "Requests and bookings",
      fill: false,
      lineTension: 0.1,
      backgroundColor: bubbleBackgroundColor(),
      borderColor: bubbleBorderColor(),
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      borderDash: [],
      borderDashOffset: 0.0,
      borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
      pointBorderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
      pointBorderWidth: 1,
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(153, 102, 155, 0.2)",
      pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(153, 102, 155, 1)",
      pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
      pointRadius: 1,
      pointHitRadius: 10,
      // how would the data change ...how can the numbers for y be replaced with strings
      data:[{x: "Mon",y: "Tue",r: 15},{x: "Tue",y:  "Thu",r: 19},{x: "wed",y:  "wed",r: 50}]
    }]
  };


  var ctx = document.getElementById('bubble');
  var bubble = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bubble',
    data: bubbleChartData,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      title: {
        display: true,
        text:'Weekly activity'
      },
        scales: {
          y: {
              // will this create y-axis with days of week?
              type: 'category',
              labels: ["Mon", "Tue", "wed", "Thu"]
          },
          x: {
            type: 'category',
            labels: ["Mon", "Tue", "wed", "Thu"]
          }
        }
      
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<body>
<canvas id="bubble"></canvas>
</body>
```

Reference from:
https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.3.0/axes/cartesian/category.html
Here is an Example:
https://codepen.io/miguelalejo/pen/abLKwLO